# Tkinter: mini canvas windows as a slider

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas

I am new to Tkinter. I want to control the movement of the image with a cursor and a small window:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/whEzb.jpg)

I tried with this code, but the result is not really what I'm looking for.

```
import tkinter as tk
from io import BytesIO
import requests
from PIL import Image , ImageTk


def full_dimensions(imag_fs):
    top = tk.Toplevel(root)
    img = tk.Label(top, image=imag_fs)
    img.pack()


def get_image():
    _url = 'https://i.imgur.com/4m7AHVu.gif'
    _img = requests.get(_url)
    if _img.status_code == 200:
        _content = BytesIO(_img.content)
    else:
        _content = 'error.gif'
    print('image loaded')
    return _content


root = tk.Tk()

_content =  get_image()   
_x = Image.open(_content)
imag_fs = ImageTk.PhotoImage(_x)
_x.thumbnail((100, 100), Image.ANTIALIAS)

imag = ImageTk.PhotoImage(_x)
img = tk.Button(root, image=imag, command=lambda: full_dimensions(imag_fs))
img.grid(column=3, row=1)

root.mainloop()
```

I tested a window, but when I import an image I can't control

```
import tkinter as tk

main_window = tk.Tk()


def check_hand_enter():
    canvas.config(cursor="hand1")


def check_hand_leave():
    canvas.config(cursor="")


canvas = tk.Canvas(width=200, height=200)
tag_name = "polygon"

canvas.create_polygon((25, 25), (25, 100), (125, 100), (125, 25), outline='black', fill="", tag=tag_name)

canvas.tag_bind(tag_name, "<Enter>", lambda event: check_hand_enter())
canvas.tag_bind(tag_name, "<Leave>", lambda event: check_hand_leave())

canvas.pack()
main_window.mainloop()
```

Comment: I don't see any attempt at all for trying to scroll around in the image.  It's not clear what the problem is, other than you not trying to solve the problem before asking the question.

Comment: So the thing is that I made the code to do this or more like an example of code, but I would like to first see Your actual attempt on this or at the very least a detailed pseudo-code

Comment: I tried but can't do it just because I'm a beginner. I need to see your code it will help me a lot

Comment: what did You try exactly? could You show Your attempts. You just told that You tried, so where exactly did You not succeed? Like at least show Your attempts. Also if You could write a pretty detailed pseudocode of how that would work I could maybe show You the code too, because I need You to try not just give You the code for free otherwise it won't help much or maybe I can just explain stuff, but... I want to see what You have done

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I put a reproducible code, to meet the requirements of stackoverflow. But I updated my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here is how I would do this (a simple example):

```py
# import all necessary modules and classes
from tkinter import Tk, Canvas, Frame
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import requests

# checking if the file exists, if it doesn't exist download it, if can't download it, exit the program
try:
    open('space.jpg')
except FileNotFoundError:
    url = 'https://images5.alphacoders.com/866/866360.jpg'
    img = requests.get(url)
    if img.status_code == 200:
        with open('space.jpg', 'wb') as file:
            file.write(img.content)
        print('File not found. Downloaded the necessary file.')
    else:
        print('File not found. Could not download the necessary file.')
        exit()


class MovableImage(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent

        # dictionary for storing information about movement
        self.start_coords = {'x': 0, 'y': 0, 'move': False}

        # dictionary for storing information about movement
        self.start_coords_main = {'x': 0, 'y': 0, 'move': False}

        # loads the image
        self.image = Image.open('space.jpg')
        # sets the images to their corresponding variables so that they can be referenced later
        # resizes the smaller image to fit the navigation window
        self.main_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.image)
        self.nav_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.image.resize((200, 100), Image.ANTIALIAS))

        # creates the canvas to store the bigger image on
        self.main_canvas = Canvas(self, width=700, height=500, highlightthickness=0)
        self.main_canvas.pack()
        # puts image on canvas
        self.main_image_id = self.main_canvas.create_image((0, 0), image=self.main_image, anchor='nw', tags='main_image')

        # creates the smaller canvas that will be used for navigation
        self.nav_canvas = Canvas(self.main_canvas, width=200, height=100, highlightthickness=0)
        # adds the smaller canvas as a window to the main_canvas
        self.main_canvas.create_window((500, 400), window=self.nav_canvas, anchor='nw', tags='nav_canvas')
        # adds the resized image to nav_canvas
        self.nav_canvas.create_image((0, 0), image=self.nav_image, anchor='nw')
        # creates a rectangle to indicate the current view of the image
        self.nav_box = self.nav_canvas.create_rectangle((0, 0, 70, 50), outline='white')

        # binds functions
        self.main_canvas.bind('<Button-1>', self.set_start_coords_main)
        self.main_canvas.bind('<B1-Motion>', self.move_coords_main)

        # binds functions
        self.nav_canvas.bind('<Button-1>', self.set_start_coords)
        self.nav_canvas.bind('<B1-Motion>', self.move_coords)

    # function that sets the starting coords so that they can be referenced later, also sets whether the box can be moved at all
    def set_start_coords(self, event):
        x1, y1, x2, y2 = self.nav_canvas.coords(self.nav_box)
        if x1 < event.x < x2 and y1 < event.y < y2:
            self.start_coords['x'] = event.x - x1
            self.start_coords['y'] = event.y - y1
            self.start_coords['move'] = True
        else:
            self.start_coords['move'] = False

    # the moving part, this takes reference from the starting coords and uses them for calculation
    # basic border checks and then the actual moving
    def move_coords(self, event):
        if not self.start_coords['move']:
            return

        dx = self.start_coords['x']
        dy = self.start_coords['y']
        x = event.x - dx
        y = event.y - dy

        if x < 0:
            x = 0
        elif x + 70 > 200:
            x = 130
        if y < 0:
            y = 0
        elif y + 50 > 100:
            y = 50

        self.nav_canvas.coords(self.nav_box, x, y, x + 70, y + 50)
        self.main_canvas.coords(self.main_image_id, -x * 10, -y * 10)

    # function that sets the starting coords so that they can be referenced later, also sets whether the box can be moved at all
    def set_start_coords_main(self, event):
        x1, y1, x2, y2 = self.main_canvas.bbox('main_image')
        if x1 < event.x < x2 and y1 < event.y < y2:
            self.start_coords_main['x'] = event.x - x1
            self.start_coords_main['y'] = event.y - y1
            self.start_coords_main['move'] = True
        else:
            self.start_coords_main['move'] = False

    # the moving part, this takes reference from the starting coords and uses them for calculation
    # basic border checks and then the actual moving
    def move_coords_main(self, event):
        if not self.start_coords_main['move']:
            return

        dx = self.start_coords_main['x']
        dy = self.start_coords_main['y']
        x = event.x - dx
        y = event.y - dy

        if x < -1300:
            x = -1300
        elif x > 0:
            x = 0
        if y < -500:
            y = -500
        elif y > 0:
            y = 0

        self.nav_canvas.coords(self.nav_box, -x / 10, -y / 10, -x / 10 + 70, -y / 10 + 50)
        self.main_canvas.coords(self.main_image_id, x, y)


# basic Tk() instance and afterwards the root.mainloop()
root = Tk()

MovableImage(root).pack()

# mainloop
root.mainloop()
```

Few things to mention: this is a pretty hardcoded sample that pretty much works well with only images whose resolution is 2000x1000 pixels, other images may not be shown correctly or resizing won't look as good. With this issue You will have to deal Yourself or ask another question about what **issues** You encountered while trying to make this adjustable. So it would be great if any image could be put up there and it would work.

**About the code**, it is pretty simple:

**Import modules**

**check for file** (there could be a better way but this works too), then if the file does not exist just download it, if that can't be done, well just exit the program.

Then setting up **some references** (a dictionary so that `global` doesn't have to be used and also I would say that a dictionary is better for other reasons too like all the necessary variables are in one place and for example `x` and `y` variable names are not taken globally).

Then setting the **first function which will register the mouse click.** This is done to get the position of mouse relative to the moveable square (basically where is the mouse on the square if the square was an independent window or sth) and it is made possible to move, but before that the function checks if the mouse is inside the square at all. If not moving is disabled so that for example if You were to click outside of the square and start moving it does not do that.

Then the **moving function is defined**. There the relative x and y coords are retrieved but first it checks if it can move and if it cannot, it stops the execution of that function. Then some more calculations and checking for border (again this is pretty hardcoded and should be changed to a more dynamic function so that it can detect this based on picture). Then comes the moving part which just move both the navigation box and the actual picture to their according spots (this is somewhat hardcoded but basically if You were to keep the scale to 1/10 of the smaller box, then this specific part would work with different images).

Then comes the **basic `Tk()` initiation and later the `.mainloop()`**.

In the middle just **open the image** and set it to 2 variables and resize the one that will go to the navigation box.

Then **create the main canvas** where the main image will be shown.

Then **add that image** to canvas and keep the id reference so that the image can be later moved.

**Create the smaller canvas** and don't pack it or anything but add the instance as a window to the main canvas so that it is on top of it (as in the photo in Your question). Again it is placed in a hardcoded manner.

Then **add the navigation image** to the navigation canvas and add the small box that will be moved too.

Then **bind functions** to mouse activity in `nav_canvas`.

If You have questions ask. **Note that** the `try/except` is not necessary if You are using Your own images and it will always come with the program. It is there because You may not have this exact picture with those exact dimensions with that exact name so it is kinda temporary for testing purposes.

EDIT: put code in a `class` that inherits from `Frame` so that this can be placed as a widget.

Comment: Great thanks a lot. Is it possible to move both at the same time? Move the canvas, and move the mini window? Because Canvas is frozen

Comment: What do You mean by _at the same time_? They do move at the same time, as soon as You move the white rectangle around in the `nav_canvas`, it will immediately move the image. Also there is no need to move the Canvas, just move the objects inside it.

Comment: A bit confused here. Do You want to be able to move the image just by mouse without any mini windows? because the image You showed had a miniwindow? or is it just supposed to show where on image the user is? Well then basically reverse the functionality

Comment: Added code to do what I think You meant. (At the end of the answer)

Comment: Actually, I want to be able to move with the mouse and with the mini-window. Because in the image I can move both with the mini-window and with the mouse on the canvas. And if you can help me integrate the mini-window into my count that would be great. Thank you

Comment: Just combine both codes and it will work fine, just remember to name functions and dictionaries somewhat else

Comment: Added a pretty much combination of both codes, nothing much, just copy-pasted function from one code to the other, why couldn't You just do that? (obviously had to rename a few things, but...)

Comment: Your given code is way too long, just create another canvas and place that canvas as a window on the main canvas, as shown in my code.

Comment: I have a question: you are in which country? Are you available to be a consultant or something like that?

Comment: I typically cannot be reached because I have really never thought of consulting (I have had that idea, but...) and even if I were doing that outside of StackOverflow, I wouldn't do it for free (unless for someone I knew) but I will think about this, as for the question You posted there on CodeReview I don't think it will be really answered but I don't know much about that site but I think that it is more about making performance better or sth, but as I said I don't know. Also I don't think that that kind of question can be asked on StackOverflow (which is meant for specific problem solving)

Comment: Also I am not entirely sure how You have set up Your whole GUI, but You could embed this whole thing in a Frame and put it all in a class and then just show this frame (which I can actually show You how to do)

Comment: @Mast well I _thought_ it would fit there which clearly is not the case, sorry for inconvenience, I just didn't know where else to put it. I guess the part where the code already has to work wasn't met

Comment: @Matiiss Yes, that's exactly what I want. Can you share an example of this with me please?

Comment: @Matiiss My code is there maybe you can have an indication of how to embed it https://pastebin.com/0qpkKkRZ

Comment: @ZacCherbourg I edited the code. Now the class can be used as a widget so You should have no problem with putting it in Your GUI

Comment: Is it possible to replace (500, 400) with values from the canvas so that it is always top and right? Because I have a resizable canvas, and the mini window often moves. Do you have an email for consultations? And you are from which country?

Comment: ok, before You asked this, did You try replacing those coordinates? for top right they would be something like `(canvas_width - min_win_width, 0)` where `canvas_width` could be retrieved from sth like `canvas.bind('<Configure>', func)` and then `def func(event):` and `print(event)` and You will see that there is some data also regarding the size of canvas so could be used to detect `canvas_width` whereas `min_win_width` is just the width of the small window.I don't have email for consultations at least not yet and why does it matter from which country I am?

Comment: Thank you for all your help, you are a genius. I rephrased in a new question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67575768/tkinter-resizable-canvas-rectangle-at-bottom-left. Promise this is the last time I disturb you. And if you are a consultant, I would like to work with you on other projects. Country doesn't matter

Comment: Yes, I was actually just now looking at it since I found it in the recent questions. I am not really a consultant (not professionally at least) but I can sort of freelance consulting, tho for sth like that I would like to get paid, but otherwise You can just ask questions here on StackOverflow if You have specific issues. Btw are You a student?

Comment: Yes I am a student, and you ?

Comment: I am a student too.

Comment: For freelance consulting how can I contact you?

Comment: I did not get your answer

Comment: well I have not yet thought about it, wait a minute will answer

Comment: ok, here is my email for consultations (don't know how often I will check it tho, but hopefully I will do it enough) Python Consultant:
`python.consultation@gmail.com`